# Making a canvas animation a background element on a parent div

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

Currently I have this piece of code running a canvas animation that shows subtle stars moving and sparkling. Currently the canvas is it's own element but I'm wanting to move it to be a background element on a parent div. Can anybody show me how to do this. JS fiddle attached here - https://jsfiddle.net/83aahcng/

```
<div id="container">
    <canvas id="pixie"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just put a div over pixie like this... [div over pixie](https://jsfiddle.net/chicodemilo/bpk19n7h/1/).

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="over_stuff">
 Here's some stuff over #pixie!
</div>
<canvas id="pixie"></canvas>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
z-index: 1;
}
#pixie {
z-index:0;
background:#010222;
background: 
}
#over_stuff{
color:white;
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
z-index:5;
padding:10px;
}
```

Is there is something I'm not understanding? This seems way too simple

Comment: Hey Miles, thanks for the answer. Yeah that's the way I'm going to do it if I can't find a way to assign it as a background to another div. I'm just not a huge fan of the absolute content option.

Comment: No problem @FrazerFindlater - maybe someone else will have a more elegant solution for us. This may help you too: [background](http://jsfiddle.net/6t3xX/1/).

Comment: An html element background can't be (efficiently) animated with javascript so Miles' `position:absolute` is probably your best solution.

Comment: Hey @Miles I ended up using your answer. Was totally the easy way! Thanks again.

Comment: No problem - happy to help!